# MariaDB Fails to Start with SELinux Enabled

Tags: mariadb, selinux

I upgraded the **mysql5.1** to **MariaDB5.5** on my CentOS6.8 SELinux server. The command **service mysql start** fails to start mysql service. If I use **setenforce 0** then I can start mysql service and everything works, until a reboot.

getsebool reports: (I tested changing allow_user_mysql_connect to 'on')

> allow_user_mysql_connect --> off
>
> mysql_connect_any --> on

I searched and found a question stating to set permissions on the **var/lib/mysql** directory:

> chcon -Rt mysqld_db_t mysql
>
> chcon -Ru system_u mysql

The aboved did not solve the fail to start problem. What else do I need to configure in SELinux to have mysql service run with SELInux enabled?

Thanks

Comment: Check this: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/what-to-do-if-mariadb-doesnt-start/#selinux -- maybe you'll find a solution for your variation of the problem, there are many.

Comment: I went through that article prior to posting, which resulted in peforming the chcon commands as described. The solution I found was to set user=mysql in the my.cnf file.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing my backups, the **my.cnf** file had set **user=mysql**. Once I added user=mysql to the new my.cnf file everything worked. The upgrade had created a new my.cnf file, as expected, which no longer had the setting user=mysql.